# Installing Steam on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, steam

I have ran into some issues when it went down to install Steam on Debian. The console as well as Apper comes up with missing dependencies  and the package isn't going to install.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better yet, just install the Steam package provided in the non-free repository hosted on Debian's infrastructure:

- add `i386`

  `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
- edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to enable `contrib` and `non-free`; the `jessie` line should look something like (the URL will be different)

  `deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free`

  (replace with `stretch` for Debian 9, or `buster` for Debian 10)
- update `apt`'s caches

  `sudo apt-get update`
- install Steam

  `sudo apt-get install steam:i386`
- install the appropriate 3D libraries (`libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` for Mesa, `libgl1-fglrx-glx:i386` for fglrx on AMD GPUs, or `libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386` for the NVIDIA binary driver; note that fglrx is no longer available in Debian 9 and later):

  `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Steam will update itself as necessary.

Comment: In my case after installing `steam` package, I wasn't able to run it with the error being `command not found: steam`.

After some digging around, I had to run the `/usr/games/steam` which wasn't in my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research and some trying myself, I found a fairly easy fix, that made the package install and steam running.

First of all you need the client, if you haven't already:

```
$ wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam_latest.deb
```

Once you got the client downloaded, try to install the steam_latest.deb package. In CLI as well as in Apper or Gdebi you will get an error.

The error is a result of dependency problems which we will look into next:

```
# sudo dpkg -i steam_newest.deb
```

You should see something like this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 82762 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack steam.deb ...
Unpacking steam-launcher (1.0.0.49) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
steam-launcher depends on curl; however: 
Package curl is not installed.
steam-launcher depends on zenity; however:   
Package zenity is not installed.
```

You should also see something like this:

```
dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...   
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:  
steam-launcher
```

Now we will work on install all dependencies required to install Steam client:

```
# sudo apt-get -f install
```

With this command, it should be possible, to install steam client successfully on your system. However, the client won't run still if you don't have 32-bit libraries installed. To do so, you need to enable multi-arch:

```
# sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
# sudo apt-get update
```

Next, you have to install all required 32bit libraries:

```
# apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
```

Also, depending on the graphic card you are using, you might have to install binary OpenGL 32-bit libraries. If you dont, you will see an error message like this, when you run the steam client:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

This is resolved by installing the OpenGL 32-bit libraries suitable for your VGA type:

```
NVIDIA:
# sudo apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx-i386
ATI/AMD:
# sudo apt-get install  libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386
```

With that done, you should now be able to start your steam client.

```
$ steam
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Flatpak.

```
apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam
flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam
```