# Debian won't install steam

Tags: debian, apt, steam

I want to follow this guide :

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-client-on-debian-9-stretch-linux

this answer does not work either :[Installing Steam on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264004/installing-steam-on-debian)

it does not work for me.

I get :

```
sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam
```

I am on debian 9 (stretch) 64bit

my current source.list :

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.9.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190427-10:30]/ stretch main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.9.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190427-10:30]/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

Comment: guys I don't think you're taking this seriously. debian just broke this. it no longer works. you now have to edit sources first. but I don't know what source.

Comment: I am taking this seriously, I have re-verified this. You’re right that you need to edit `sources.list`, and the linked answer tells you exactly what to add. The article you referred to yourself also tells you what to add.

Comment: To spell it out: your `sources.list` shows that you missed this part of the explanations in both links, you need to add `contrib non-free` to the first two `stretch` lines, `deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Please run the following command at first:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Now, you need to enable 32-bit support:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then, install the Steam package:

```
apt install steam
```

Comment: does not work. exact same result.

Comment: If you think you're able to solve your issue, please don't ask others to solve your problem.